# Need to display multiple records related to same clientname

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I have written an API in nodejs which will fetch all the related records based on the client-name given.And in angular i'm using dropdown to select client-name with unique names.So far it is working fine, but i want to display all the related data(if one client-name contains 2-3 different records).But it is fetching only one row's data when i select client-name.

Here's my working API which i have checked it with postman:

```
  router.get('/getbyname/:clientname',function(req,res){

     var clientname= req.params.clientname;
    Quotation.find({clientname: clientname} ,function(err,user){
        if(err){
            res.json({ success: false, message: 'Can\'t display details'});
        }else{
            res.json(user);
        }
    });
});
```

In angular i'm using below piece of code to get all data and filter by client-name from quotation table:

```
 var onPersonGetCompleted01 = function(response){
      $scope.quotations = response.data;
       //console.log($scope.quotations);
  }


    var refreshQuotation = function(){
      $http.get('/api/getallquotations')
        .then(onPersonGetCompleted01);
      console.log('Response received...');
    }


  var onGetByName = function(response){
        $scope.clientname = response.data;
        console.log(response.data);

    };

    $scope.searchPerson = function(clientname){
        $http.get('/api/getbyname/' + clientname)
                .then(onGetByName);
        console.log(clientname);
    };
```

In view i'm having selection like this:

```
 <select ng-model="clientSelected" ng-options="quote.clientname for quote in quotations | unique:'clientname'" ng-click="searchPerson(quote.clientname)">

<option value="0">Default</option>
```

No problem with selecting the data based on clientname. But i just want to know how to display the related data with the same clientname. Since there are more than 2-3 documents.

If i use like this it will fetch only one row's data:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="email">UOM:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" required id="email" 
   placeholder=""  name="projectid" ng-model=clientSelected.uom>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display multiple documents with same clientname then we should be replaing `| unique:'clientname'` with `track by $index` in ng-options part. So the final ng-options code will be `ng-options="quote.clientname for quote in quotations track by $index"`

Comment: If i remove `unique:'clientname'`, it will display the duplicate values also.But i want to show unique names and display the multiple records data for the same clientname. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think i'm close to get my required output, now  i can able to get all the related values(rows) in console after making a slight change in the **select** tag.

```
    <select  class="chosen-select form-control col-sm-3" ng-
    model="clientSelected" ng-options="quote.clientname for quote in 
    quotations | unique: 'clientname'" ng-
    click="searchPerson(clientSelected.clientname)" >
    <option value="0">Default</option>   
  </select>
```

Initially i was passing **quote.clientname** `searchPerson(quote.clientname)` as an argument, now i changed it to `searchPerson(clientSelected.clientname)`. It's working fine now.